# ComboBox in DatagridView in Edit Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with read-only mode set to true (non-editable) which takes values from a database on form load. When I set the read-only mode to false (editable mode), I want a particular column (eg. Department) to visible as ComboBox so i can select values from there. And when i enter the Read-Only mode, the ComboBox should disappear and DataGridView should be visible as normal. How to achieve it?
I am using C# framework 4.0, Winforms

Comment: What do you mean by `disappear`?  You want the entire column to be hidden, or just the combobox to be disabled (ie. the user can not select the drop down list from the combobox?

Comment: I mean, the datagridview be in its normal mode and combobox diappear but not the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the implementation at [ComboBox with read only behavior](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9952/ComboBox-with-Read-Only-Behavior).

You could also change the [`DisplayStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.displaystyle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) based on when the readonly of the `DataGridView` property is changed.  Setting the `DisplayStyle` to [`DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxdisplaystyle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) will hide the drop down button.

For example, changing the `ReadOnly` property with a button click would look something like this:

```
private void mChangeReadOnlyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBoxColumn2.DisplayStyle = (dataGridView1.ReadOnly) ?
      DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox :
      DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
   dataGridView1.ReadOnly = !dataGridView1.ReadOnly;
}
```

Editable:

[image: Editable]

ReadOnly:

[image: ReadOnly]

Comment: i got my solution actually, but really sorry, i deleted it by mistake. and i undeleted it now. sorry for trouble. But in my solution i am facing problem, when my rowindex and columnindex are same. your solution works fine for me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution to my problem, just thought to post it here. On entering edit mode, running the following code may solve the problem.

```
public void bgCombo(DataGridView dg)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgc = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        dgc.Value = row.Cells["Department"].Value;
        row.Cells["Department"] = dgc;
    }
}
```

Before setting dgc to dataGridCell we can add items collections in it. Hope it helps.

PROBLEM: If the Column and Row index, becomes same while editing, i am getting an error - Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

Comment: I love this post. everything else i found on the net was long-winded and confusing and not really what i was looking for. LIFE SAVER!! :)

Comment: I am glad to have such comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide a combobox for selected rows you can use the  DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle property

The options are ComboBox, DropdownBox or None

In the example - only display the ComboBox in column 4 if there is a value in column 2

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows  
        Dim Cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(row.Cells(4), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)  
    Cell.ReadOnly = True  
    Cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing  
    If row.Cells(2).Value IsNot Nothing Then  
        Cell.ReadOnly = False  
        Cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox  
    End If  
Next
```