# How to compare DropDown value and GridView column value, and hide if they are different

Tags: c#, gridview, dropdownlistfor

How to compare DropDownList value and GridView column value, and hide if they are different?

I have 5 columns. In the first and in the second are values from DropdownList, and the others are results from some DMX query. I should hide the values in third column if they are not the same as the user select in DropDownList

I tried many solutions, but they do not work. Last, I tried this function. Thank you in advance!

private void GenerateUniqueData()
    {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        DataControlFieldCell cell = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] as DataControlFieldCell;
        if (cell.Text!=DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Value)
            GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to happen when you edit / add a row? If this is ASP .NET, why would you make a round trip to the server, couldn't you use JavaScript?

Comment: Hey Mary, you could look at this stackoverflow posting for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448471/combobox-in-datagridview-in-edit-mode

Comment: @Mary I think we need to see a bit more code. this is ASP.NET right?

Comment: In fact thinking about it more, @AlexFilipovici hit the nail on the head. Although I'd use JQuery, this sounds like a great fit for client side code.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, this is in ASP.NET, and I want do that as the last activity, after the user enter value, and query is done. Just to hide specific rows if the value is not same as selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article. Too much to cover here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43727/Show-Hide-GridView-Columns-in-ASP-NET

Edit:
Let's try it in plain ASP.NET with code behind:
First thing to check, did you switch on **AutoPostBack** on the DropDownList? If there is no round trip to the server none of your code makes any difference, it will not get executed.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here's a working example...
HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DataGridTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataGridTest" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class DataGridTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> ddData = new List<string>();
            ddData.Add("Col 21");
            ddData.Add("Col 22");
            ddData.Add("Col 23");

            this.DropDownList1.DataSource = ddData;
            this.DropDownList1.DataBind();

            DataTable gridData = new DataTable();
            gridData.Columns.Add("Description");
            gridData.Columns.Add("Column 1");
            gridData.Columns.Add("Column 2");
            gridData.Columns.Add("Column 3");

            gridData.Rows.Add("Row 1", "Col 11", "Col 21", "Col 31");
            gridData.Rows.Add("Row 2", "Col 12", "Col 22", "Col 32");
            gridData.Rows.Add("Row 3", "Col 13", "Col 23", "Col 33");
            gridData.Rows.Add("Row 3", "Col 14", "Col 22", "Col 34");

            this.GridView1.DataSource = gridData;
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            this.GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;

            string cellvalue = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            if (cellvalue.TrimEnd() != this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.TrimEnd())
                GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, I tried this, and now everything is hidden in gridview... But I have same values in dropdownlist and gridview column.

Comment: Try to trim the text values, some data types have trailing spaces added in the database. So: if (cellvalue.TrimEnd() != this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.TrimEnd())